# MySQL - Joining same table twice, parent sum column value getting duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just 3 months of experience in MySQL. Here I'm trying to generate a report based on log and part table. When trying to join the "Part" table twice, the "Log" table Quantity gets doubled. Kindly let me know where I'm doing wrong.

**Log Table**

[image]

**Part Table**

[image]

**Expected Report**

[image]

Query Used

```
SELECT 
report.*,
(SUM(report.quantity)) AS totalQuantity,
normalPart.price AS normalPrice,
premiumPart.price AS premiumPrice
FROM
log AS report
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    part AS normalPart
WHERE
    normalPart.type = 'normal'
GROUP BY normalPart.partNumber , normalPart.genId) AS normalPart ON report.partNumber = normalPart.partNumber
    AND report.genId = normalPart.genId
    AND normalPart.cat = report.fromCat
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    *
FROM
    part AS premiumPart
WHERE
    premiumPart.type = 'premium'
GROUP BY premiumPart.partNumber , premiumPart.genId) AS premiumPart ON report.partNumber = premiumPart.partNumber
    AND report.genId = premiumPart.genId
    AND premiumPart.cat = report.toCat;
```

**Query Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original version of the question.

Aggregate before you join:

```
select l.*, p.normal_price, p.premium_price
from (select genid, partnumber, sum(quantity) as quantity
      from log
      group by genid, partnumber
     ) l left join
     (select partnumber, genid,
             max(case when type = 'normal' then price end) as normal_price,
             max(case when type = 'premium' then price end) as premium_price
      from part
      group by partnumber, genid
     ) p
     on p.partnumber = l.partnumber and p.genid = l.genid
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Sorry, I forgot to add one more validation and updated the same in the Query. Need to get the price based on the another key(fromCat or toCat) form the log table.